# XmlDocument XPath expression failing

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

I am using C# XmlDocument API.

I have the following XML:

```
<Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node3>
        </Node3>
    </Node2>
</Node1>
```

I want to get Node3 as an XmlNode. But my code is returning null:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
XmlNode root_node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Node1");

Log(root_node.OuterXml);
XmlNode test_node = root_node.SelectSingleNode("/Node2/Node3");

if (test_node == null)
    Logger.Log.Error(" --- TEST NODE IS NULL --- ");
```

The log for `root_node.OuterXml` logs

```
<Node1><Node2><Node3>.....
```

But `test_node` returns null.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: test_node to be scoped to Node3, and not be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the path `"Node2/Node3"` instead of `"/Node2/Node3"`:

```
XmlNode test_node = root_node.SelectSingleNode("Node2/Node3");
```

In an XPath expression, a leading forward slash `/` represents the root of the document. The expression `"/Node2/Node3"` doesn't work because `<Node2>` isn't at the root of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Use // instead of /, when you are selecting from the root node

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
XmlNode root_node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Node1");
XmlNode test_node = root_node.SelectSingleNode("//Node2/Node3");
```

Another option is to use full path to the node 3

```
XmlNode test_node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Node1/Node2/Node3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple call `Descendants()`

```
 var xml= @"<Node1><Node2><Node3></Node3></Node2></Node1>";
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 var node = doc.Descendants("Node3");
```

or use `Element()` starting from `Root`

```
   var node2= doc.Root.Element("Node2").Element("Node3");
```

or use `XPathSelectElement()`

```
 var node3=  doc.XPathSelectElement("/Node1/Node2/Node3");
```